# how to convert timezone GMT offsets (-0700, -0600, etc) to actual timezone (America/New_York, America/Los_Angeles, etc) in snowflake automatically?

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timezone-offset

Is it possible in snowflake to convert a timestamp using a timezone offset to a specific timezone at runtime?

I have a source timestamp column in MST and another column for target timezone offset like -0700. I want to convert the source MST timestamp to the target timestamp (offset values are different). Is it possible in snowflake using convert_timezone function? I know I have to first get the target timezone using the offset then use the function to convert the MST timestamp.

Can anyone help me how it can be done keeping change in DST automatic?

Comment: There's no single mapping from a UTC offset to a time zone. For example, "Africa/Casablanca" and "Europe/London" both use UTC+0 and UTC+1 - but changing at different times. So if you had an offset of UTC+1, which time zone would you expect that to map to?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you actually need a target time zone though - if you know the target offset, then you should be fine so long as you know the source offset. That depends on what you mean by "MST" though. If you actually mean "Mountain Time" then you'd need to work out whether you mean UTC-6 or UTC-7 for any given value; if it's *always* UTC-7, then that's much simpler.